# When I try to use psql, it asks for password of a user that doesn't exists

Tags: windows, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL (I installed it today) and I am trying to use Django with it. That is not the issue. The problem is that when I run `psql postgres`, it prompts for a password of a user `joaqu`. This is my Windows user. However, I never set up that password. The installer did ask for a password in the installing process, but it was for the `postgres` user. This password does work, however, since I never set up the other one, I am not able to use `psql postgres`.

I tried running `psql -U postgres` (with that `-U` it prompts for postgres password), and then run `ALTER USER joaqu PASSWORD 'my password';`, but it answered with `ERROR:  no existe el rol «joaqu»` (which is translated to 'The roll 'joaqu' doesn't exists')

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to create that user before you can use it. `postgres` is the only default user right after an installation.

Comment: You are mixing system and database user names. When you do `psql postgres` you are asking to connect to database `postgres` as the system user `psql` is running as, in this case `joaqu`. You need to specify a database user with `-U` as you found out. The `ALTER` command does not work as there is no database user `joaqu` yet. You need to to do `CREATE ROLE joaqu ...` first. Get used to using `ROLE` not `USER` as `USER` is deprecated.

Comment: Ohhhh. Thank you both very much. I'm sorry if this question is stupid hehe. @AdrianKlaver

Answer (score 3):

use this instade of `psql`

```
psql -U <username>
```

e.g.

```
psql -U postgres
```

as `postgres` is default username most of the time.

[image]